# Failed to execute MI command -var-create in Eclipse CDT IDE

Tags: eclipse, error-handling, compiler-errors, eclipse-cdt

i have this problem :

```
causale char [256]  Error: Multiple errors reported.\
Failed to execute MI command: -var-create - * &((lista).causale) Error message from debugger back end: Type struct list_element has no component named causale.\
Failed to execute MI command: -data-evaluate-expression (lista).causale Error message from debugger back end: There is no member named causale.\
Failed to execute MI command: -var-create - * &((lista).causale) Error message from debugger back end: Type struct list_element has no component named causale.\ 
Unable to create variable object
```

I don't understand if is a Eclipse ( Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers Version: Juno Service Release 2) problem or a error in my code.Reading the error report  seems that is a error in my code but i can't correct it.Can anybody help me ? Thanks :)

this is my code : 
**Main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "pagamenti.h"
int main ( )
{
char nomeFile [] = "20130613";
list l = NULL;

l = leggiPagamenti(nomeFile);

showList ( l );
system("PAUSE");
}
```

**element.h**

```
#ifndef ELEMENT_H_
#define ELEMENT_H_
typedef struct
{
int idCliente;
int idPagamento;
float importo;
char causale [ 256 ];
} Pagamento;
typedef Pagamento element;
#endif /* ELEMENT_H_ */
```

**list.h**

```
#ifndef LIST_H_
#define LIST_H_
#include "element.h"

typedef struct  list_element {
    element value;
    struct list_element  *next; } item;

typedef  item* list;

typedef  int boolean;

/*  PROTOTIPI DI FUNZIONE (extern) */

/* PRIMITIVE  */ list emptylist(void); boolean empty(list); list cons(element, list); element head(list); list tail(list); void showList(list l);


#endif /* LIST_H_ */
```

**pagamenti.h**

```
#ifndef PAGAMENTI_H_
#define PAGAMENTI_H_
#include "list.h"
list leggiPagamenti ( char *nomeFile );

#endif /* PAGAMENTI_H_ */
```

**list.c**

```
#include "element.h"
#include "list.h"
#define NULL 0
/* OPERAZIONI PRIMITIVE */
list  emptylist(void)       /* costruttore lista vuota */
{ return NULL; }

boolean  empty(list l)  /* verifica se lista vuota */
{ return (l==NULL); }

list  cons(element e, list l)
{ list t;       /* costruttore che aggiunge in testa alla lista */
  t=(list)malloc(sizeof(item));
  t->value=e;
  t->next=l;
  return(t);
}

element  head(list l) /* selettore testa lista */
{ if (empty(l)) exit(-2);
  else return (l->value);
}

list  tail(list l)         /* selettore coda lista */
{ if (empty(l)) exit(-1);
  else return (l->next);
}


void showList(list l) {
// NON PRIMITIVE
printf("[");
while (!empty(l)) {
printf("id cliente : %d id pagamento : %d importo : %.2f causale  : %s \n",head(l).idCliente,head(l).idPagamento,head(l).importo,head(l).causale );
l = tail(l);

} printf("]\n");
}
```

**pagamenti.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "pagamenti.h"
#include "element.h"

list leggiPagamenti ( char *nomeFile )
{
element el ;
list lista = NULL;
FILE *f;
char car;
int count = 0;

        if ( ( f =  fopen  ( nomeFile , "r") ) == NULL  )
        {
            printf("Errore apertura file ");
            exit ( 1 );
        }

        while ( ( fscanf (f,"%d %d %f ",&el.idCliente,&el.idPagamento,&el.importo))> 0 )
        {
            while ( ( car = fgetc(f)) != '\n' && ( car != EOF ))
            {
                el.causale[count] = car;
                count++;
            }
            count = 0;
            lista = cons ( el, lista );


        }
        fclose ( f );
return lista;


}
```

Ok ,the same code run on visual studio , is a problem into eclipse setting maybe

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13678923/eclipse-failed-to-execute-mi-command What actions trigger the error? For me: trying to explore the variable value in the "Variables" view.