# GDB in Eclipse CDT: Failed to execute MI command / program terminated with signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have trouble getting GDB to work in Eclipse CDT. Here is my situation / sequence of events:

- I'm on Mac OS Sierra 10.12.4
- Eclipse CDT version 4.6.3
- I installed GDB following the instructions [here](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~pattis/common/handouts/macmingweclipse/allexperimental/mac-gdb-install.html) - everything went smoothly: I code-signed the executable and pointed Eclipse to it
- I opened an existing project in Eclipse that is error-free, i.e. a project that I know is working - it compiles, it runs, all good.
- I started the debug mode in Eclipse.
- Before Eclipse could even enter the debug mode, I got the following error message in a pop-up dialog titled 'Problem Occurred' right away:

"'Launching [Exectuable]' has encountered a problem.

Error in final launch sequence

Details:"

```
Error in final launch sequence
     Failed to execute MI command:
     -exec-run
Error message from debugger back end:
During startup program terminated with signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
During startup program terminated with signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
```

[Executable] is a placeholder for the executable I was trying to launch. I'm not quite sure what to do with this error message.

1. How can I find out why Eclipse failed to execute the MI command?
2. Why did the program terminate with a trace/breakpoint trap? I didn't even set any breakpoints.

Comment: Something Sierra specific. Many result on Google, all of them about it. https://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?topic=34371.0

Comment: Thanks @EugeneSh., it's indeed Sierra-specific as it seems, or System Integrity Protection-specific to be more precise. I've just turned off SIP and now GDB works in Eclipse. Thanks for pointing me towards this.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22640787/debugging-in-eclipse-using-gdb-on-mac-failed-to-execute-mi-command-exec-run | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13678923/eclipse-failed-to-execute-mi-command-target-select-remote